# get many lines randomly form a file without shuffling them

Tags: file, unix, random

I need to, using a UNIX command line script, get 11 random lines from a file that are grouped together. For instance

Random source file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
############
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
```

Running `./myscript` should give me:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

or

```
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
```

Comment: Are the block of lines separated by `####` as you have in your example? or is it always groups of 11?

Comment: shute. edited the question to mean something different. Ah well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tail -n +$(($RANDOM % 
     ($(wc -l "$filename" | cut -d' ' -f1) - 11))) "$filename" |
     head -n 11
```

#### Tested

With

```
export filename=/etc/dictionaries-common/words
set -o xtrace
```

first time

```
~$ tail -n +$(($RANDOM % ($(wc -l "$filename" | cut -d' ' -f1) - 11))) "$filename" | head -n 11
+ head -n 11
++ wc -l /etc/dictionaries-common/words
++ cut '-d ' -f1
+ tail -n +11614 /etc/dictionaries-common/words
Moriarty's
Morin
Morin's
Morison
Morison's
Morita
Morita's
Morley
Morley's
Mormon
Mormon's
```

second time

```
~$ tail -n +$(($RANDOM % ($(wc -l "$filename" | cut -d' ' -f1) - 11))) "$filename" | head -n 11
+ head -n 11
++ wc -l /etc/dictionaries-common/words
++ cut '-d ' -f1
+ tail -n +1661 /etc/dictionaries-common/words
Beatrice
Beatrice's
Beatrix
Beatrix's
Beatriz
Beatriz's
Beau
Beau's
Beaufort
Beaufort's
Beaujolais
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
n=$((`wc -l "${file}" | cut -d' ' -f1` / 11))
m=$(($RANDOM % $n))
tail -n +$(($m * 11)) "${file}" | head -n 11
```